# Javascript ternary condition operator not working as expected

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I'm making a `Row` class for a block game I'm creating. I currently have this code for the class:

```js
function Row(size, rowNum, state) {
  this.size = size;
  this.rowNum = rowNum;
  this.cells = state ? this.fromState(state) : this.empty();
}

Row.prototype.empty = function () {
  var cells = [];

  for (var x = 0; x < this.size; x++) {
    cells.push(null);
  }

  return cells;
};
Row.prototype.fromState = function (state) {
  var cells = [];


  for (var x = 0; x < this.size; x++) {
    var tile = state[this.rowNum][x];
    cells.push(tile ? new Tile(tile.position, tile.value) : null);
  }

  return cells;
};
```

I got 'position is undefined' error in tile.js. I found this was because the variable `tile` was null (and so `tile.position` was undefined).  But then, I realized I already had the ternary operator, which, supposedly, already knows that `tile` is null then pushes `null` instead of pushing `new Tile(tile.position, tile.value)`. It appears that the ternary operator is not working as expected.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Edit: For clarity: this is my constructor for `Tile`:

```
function Tile(position, value) {
  this.x                = position.x; // This is the line where I am getting the error
  this.y                = position.y; 
  this.value            = value;

  this.previousPosition = null;
  this.mergedFrom       = null; 
}
```

And the actual error:

> TypeError: position is undefined

Comment: Are you getting a position is "undefined" error or are you getting "Cannot read property 'position' of undefined".

Comment: I am getting the former.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Please check the new edits. Also, yes, I tried logging ``tile``.

Comment: If `tile.position` is `undefined`, then the `Tile` constructor cannot read the `x` and `y` properties of it. This is unrelated to your `tile` check in the conditional. You’d need to check `tile.position` instead. Try `tile?.position && tile?.value` as your condition.